# modalpopupextender asp.net usercontrol page

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I have a usercontrol as a header on a page. The usercontrol has sign up button which opens a modalpopupextender. The popup open code on sign up link is below:

```
protected void lnkSignUp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    mp1.Show();
}
```

Now I am able to successfully use this usercontrol in my page. The problem is in my page there are other links apart from header which will provide sign up facility. Now I want to use the same signup popup of usercontrol to be opened by clicking on page sign up links. What should I do on page link click. I have tried the below code from page but myMpeModal returns null:

```
ucHeaderJobseeker uc1 = new ucHeaderJobseeker();
        var myMpeModal = (AjaxControlToolkit.ModalPopupExtender)uc1.FindControl("mpeModal");
        myMpeModal.Show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing something like this:

Your Front End (.aspx Page):

```
<uc1:WebUserControl runat="server" ID="myUserControl" />
```

Your UserControl Should look like this:

```
<ajax:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpeModal" runat="server" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground"
        PopupControlID="pnlShowMe" TargetControlID="btnClickMe" CancelControlID="btnClose">
    </ajax:ModalPopupExtender>
    <asp:Button ID="btnClickMe" runat="server" Text="Click Me" OnClick="btnClickMe_Click" />
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlShowMe" runat="server" CssClass="ModalPanel">
    </asp:Panel>
```

Your Code Behind (.aspx.cs):

```
var myMpeModal = (AjaxControlToolkit.ModalPopupExtender)myUserControl.FindControl("mpeModal");
        myMpeModal.Show();
```

Here in the above code, "myUserControl" is your user control, "mpeModal" is your ModalPopupExtender id.

Use the above code where ever you want in your page to show the popup.

Comment: no need for initializing the object again. Use the same control which is listed in your aspx page.

Comment: myUserControl do not have FindControl method. It gives compilation error.